# Can not properly loop through the fetched firestore data in flutter and display it in Tabs

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, tabs, tabcontrol, stream-builder

I am trying to loop through the fetched data using `StreamBuilder` and push it to the `TabController`.

The problem is that in a `TabController` I need to set the `length` property. In my case it will be 3, but ideally it should be counted dynamically based on amount of `documents` in my `collection`.

And then in my `TapBar` I have `tabs` property, which should look like something like this:

```
 final List<Widget> myTabs = [
    Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
    Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
    Tab(text: 'Tab 3'),
  ];
```

So I am trying to generate that `myTabs` list in a `StreamBuilder`:

```
final List<Widget> finalTabs = [];
Timestamp eventTabControl = snapshot.data?.docs[index].data()['day'];
finalTabs.addAll([Tab(text: eventTabControl.toDate().toString())]);
```

but it does not work as I expect. It just generates 1 tab for me instead of 3.

### [image]

expected result is:

### [image]

However when I try to print `finalTabs` in console it displays me all my 3 values.

My whole code is:

```
import 'package:book_club/config/palette.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class EventTabControl extends StatefulWidget {
  const EventTabControl({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EventTabControl> createState() => _EventTabControlState();
}

class _EventTabControlState extends State<EventTabControl>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(length: 1, vsync: this);
    _tabController.addListener(_handleTabSelection);
    super.initState();
  }

  _handleTabSelection() {
    if (_tabController.indexIsChanging) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("schedule").snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else {
          return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                final List<Widget> finalTabs = [];
                Timestamp eventTabControl =
                    snapshot.data?.docs[index].data()['day'];
                finalTabs
                    .addAll([Tab(text: eventTabControl.toDate().toString())]);
                return Container(
                  child: Container(
                   
                    child: TabBar(
                      controller: _tabController,
                      indicatorWeight: 2.5,
                      indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                      labelColor: Palette.custGreen,
                      unselectedLabelColor: Palette.custBlue,
                      indicator: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(
                          bottom: BorderSide(
                            color: Palette.custGreen,
                            width: 2.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      tabs: finalTabs,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              });
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is just a logic for TabController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ListView Builder which is not suitable as it will render your widgets 3 times individually based on your condition ,instead, you could return tabs dynamically,

Your else part:

```
 else {   final List<Widget> finalTabs = [];
            snapshot.data?.docs.forEach((document){
            Timestamp eventTabControl = document.data()['day'];
               finalTabs.add(eventTabControl.toDate().toString());
              }
          );

          return  Container(
                   
                    child: TabBar(
                      controller: _tabController,
                      indicatorWeight: 2.5,
                      indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                      labelColor: Palette.custGreen,
                      unselectedLabelColor: Palette.custBlue,
                      indicator: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(
                          bottom: BorderSide(
                            color: Palette.custGreen,
                            width: 2.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      tabs: finalTabs.isEmpty
                      ? <Widget>[]
                      : finalTabs.map((dynamicContent) {
                          return new Text('your contentContent')),
                       );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                 
                );
              
        }
```

Comment: Thank you @Krish Bhanushali for your answer.
But I get an error here: `snapshot.data?.docs[index]` as before I got `index` from `itemBuilder: (_, index)`. How can I fix that in your version of code?

Comment: @AndriiPryimak can you check now? I have edited my answer.

Comment: This one already works, but  how can I show my retrieved values from firestore `snapshot.data?.docs[index].data()['day']` instead of `return new Text('your contentContent')`?

Comment: Nevermind @Krish Bhanushali )) I found out my problem there. Thank you very much for help!